# Cassandra Multi Node Cluster - Scan name

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

I am new to cassandra database , i have configured multi-node cassandra , configured like one node per machine
I want to access the cassandra db using one name  ( like Scan name in Oracle RAC) from client applications  is it possible to do it in that manner,
Our developers are used to the Oracle RAC scan name they are expecting something similer thing in multi node cassandra as well

At the moment I can access  the induvidual nodes using seperate IP's which i have assigned

Can any one help me on this

Comment: Hi, AFAIK there is no such feature in cassandra. Each node in the cluster needs to have one or more seed nodes setup in the config yaml. This can be DNS name or IP. More info - https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/GettingStarted, in section _Configuring Multinode Clusters_

Comment: The client applications can also these seed nodes. I am not sure of the driver that you are planning to use. The Java driver has the ability to lookup the cluster topology using any of the nodes. See - http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster.Builder.html#addContactPoint-java.lang.String-

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply , if that is the case , then Java Developer should list down all the available Node IP , in their connection stings ? is that so .. If there is 3 Nodes , then 3 IP's should be specified in the connection strings ?

Comment: It can be all three (IP or Domain names). Ideally in a cloud based environment, you will have nodes in separate racks or zones and one node from each zone or rack would be setup as a seed node.  The solution described by @Johnny M is more elegant but I am not sure if the cassandra driver will be able to lookup the topology using that.

Answer (score 0):

What I think your describing is service discovery. You should have a look at Consul (https://www.consul.io/) to define the contact points for your application to connect to Cassandra.

Essentially, you can use Consul to manage a single DNS entry (https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/dns.html) for your applications to use without having to hardcode an IP etc.